# How do I add two generic values in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

I am trying to write a function to sum an array of numeric types. This is as far as I got:

```
protocol Numeric { }
extension Float: Numeric {}
extension Double: Numeric {}
extension Int: Numeric {}

func sum<T: Numeric >(array:Array<T>) -> T{
    var acc = 0.0
    for t:T in array{
        acc = acc + t
    }
    return acc
}
```

But I don't know how to define the behaviour of the `+` operator in the `Numeric` protocol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
protocol Numeric {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}
```

should be enough.

Source: http://natecook.com/blog/2014/08/generic-functions-for-incompatible-types/

Comment: try `sum.reduce(0){ $0 + $1}`

Comment: I think for the problem descriped in the question, Bedis comment is the "more Swift" solution

Comment: @AbhishekBedi 's answer won't work without adding @Sunkas 's declaration. The problem is, if you just have an array of `Numeric`, and the `Numeric` protocol is totally empty, the compiler doesn't know how to add two of them.

Comment: Just a small addition, on Swift 4.2, the compiler requires 'static' keyword before the function.

protocol Numeric {
    static func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

Answer (score 5):

Since Swift 5, there is a built in [`AdditiveArithmetic`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/additivearithmetic) protocol which you can constrain to:

```
func sum<T: AdditiveArithmetic >(array:Array<T>) -> T{
    var acc = T.zero
    for t in array{
        acc = acc + t
    }
    return acc
}
```

Now you don't need to manually conform the built-in types to a protocol :)

Answer (score 4):

I did it like this but I was just trying to add two values and not using array but thought this might help.

```
func addTwoValues<T:Numeric>(a: T, b: T) -> T {
return a + b
}
print("addTwoValuesInts = \(addTwoValues(a: 3, b: 4))")
print("addTwoValuesDoubles = \(addTwoValues(a: 3.5, b: 4.5))")
```

Comment: This won't work unless you add the + operator to `Numeric`.

Comment: It does work.  I did that exact code in a playground and it prints out and works correctly.  Try it.

Comment: I get the error `Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'T' operands`, which is absolutely true. Say someone conformed `extension UIView: Numeric { }`. How would `addTwoValues` work with that?

Comment: you should only get that error if you don't have the numeric protocol with the T generic.  I have that code in a playground right now and it runs and prints out the correct values in the message

Comment: That is not true. If the protocol is empty (which is how the OP defined it, and how I defined it in my playground), it will not work, for the reason I stated above. It makes no sense to be able to `+` on any two objects that conform to an empty protocol. The accepted answer is what is needed.

Comment: I said my answer is a bit different but would help someone looking for adding two generics.  My answer works 100% as I have it in a playground working.  In my case I did not do a empty protocol I used the out of the box Numeric protocol and it works.

Comment: That's completely different and does not address OP's problem at all. He defined an empty protocol, which he was asking about.

Comment: I understand.  I got here looking for how to simply add two generics and saw this was a similar issue and just wanted to see if I could add to it but I tried to indicated in my post that I was doing something a little different. I was just trying to augment this a bit but I could do a new post I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This also can be achieved using extension like this

```
extension Sequence where Element: AdditiveArithmetic {
    func sum() -> Element {
        return reduce(.zero, +)
    }
}
```

And can be used like this

```
let arraySum = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5].sum()
// arraySum == 16.5

let rangeSum = (1..<10).sum()
// rangeSum == 45
```

You can refer documentation for more details
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/additivearithmetic#declaration