# Swift 5 - Generics - RangeReplaceableCollection

Tags: generics, swift5

Why this code returns a "Referencing operator function '+' on 'RangeReplaceableCollection' requires that 'T' conform to 'RangeReplaceableCollection' message ?  I really can't find what is wrong!

```
func addValues <T>(_ valA: T, _ valB: T) -> T {
   return(valA + valB)
}
     
addValues(1, 2)
addValues(1.0, 2.0)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you assume that any two things can be added together?

Comment: It seems logical that a function is able to add two numbers even using generics.

Comment: But `valA` and `valB` are not necessarily numbers. They are `T`, which could be _**anything**_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add two generic values in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046669/how-do-i-add-two-generic-values-in-swift)

Comment: OK. Thanks. I understand now. Best regards from France.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that's due to the utilization of the `+` operator in the body. The `+` operator which is of type `AdditiveArithmetic`  requires the two arguments to conform to `AdditiveArithmetic` as well. Therefore if you update your function signature to the following, that should resolve the issue.

`func addValues <T AdditiveArithmetic >(_ valA: T, _ valB: T) -> T {`

As far as why it chose to mention `RangeReplaceableCollection` , it might just be a bad warning from Apple.